# How do I write a regex pattern that does a find and replace?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a one-line regex to find multiple characters and replace them all with an underscore.

E.g.

```
Title :: How to sew

// would be

Title_How_to_sew
```

I've gotten this far:
 `const newTitle = event.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/gm, '_')`

which returns: `Title____How_to_sew`

How can I make that just one underscore per gap?

Comment: You could use `\s+(?:::)?\s*` and replace this with a single underscore.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can combine multiple regexes with the operator `|`

For example, `/(:|\s)+/` where `\s` matches any whitespace character

Adding the `+` at the end means that it will greedily swallow as many repititions as it finds, per match.